# Asynchronous and Synchronous in javaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have to use the [SP.RequestExecutor.js](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn735924.aspx) library. The problem is I need to run the async function in sync behavior. After deep search I found `await` and `async` methods but they are not compatible with Internet Explorer(IE>9). How I can make convert the async functions to sync and be compatible on IE>9 and Chrome?

```
function executorRun() {
  console.log('end2');
  var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor('path'); 
  var result=[];
  executor.executeAsync({    
      url: 'URL',
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",      
      },
      data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
      success: function (data) {
        console.log('end3')
        console.log(data);//Debug statement 
        //Handle data and store in result       
      },       
      error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
   });
  return result;
}

async function test () { 
  console.log('end1');
  const data = await executorRun();
  console.log('end4');
}

test();
```

I need the output ass follows:

> end1
>   end2
>   end3
>   end4.

The above code is running in chrome but on IE refuse the `await` and `async`.

Comment: Could you please show your code?

Comment: @Muhammad Qasim  plz see the update

Comment: those are badly formatted code

Comment: `const` [won't work](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-const) in IE9 either. You could use `var` there instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `await` to work, `executorRun` needs to return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
function executorRun() {
  console.log('end2');
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor('path'); 

    executor.executeAsync({    
        url: 'URL',
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",      
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
        success: function (data) {
          console.log('end3');
          console.log(data);//Debug statement 
          //Handle data and store in result       
          resolve(data);
        },       
        error: function (error) {
          reject(error);
          console.log(error);
        }
     });
  });
}

async function test () { 
  console.log('end1');
  const data = await executorRun();
  console.log('end4');
}

test();
```

To use `async`/`await` in IE9, you coudl transpile your code with [Babel](http://babeljs.io/).

You could also just use the `Promise` directly without the syntactic sugar of `async`/`await`:

```
function test () { 
  console.log('end1');
  executorRun().then(function (data) {
    console.log('end4');
  });
}

test();
```

IE doesn't support Promises natively, but they can easily be pollyfilled with any of the many Promise libraries out there.

If you don't want to use Promises, you could always just modify `excecutorRun` to accept a callback:

```
function executorRun(callback) {
  console.log('end2');
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor('path'); 

    executor.executeAsync({    
        url: 'URL',
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",      
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
        success: function (data) {
          console.log('end3');
          console.log(data);//Debug statement 
          //Handle data and store in result       
          callback(data);
        },       
        error: function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
     });
}

function test () { 
  console.log('end1');

  executorRun(function (data) {
    console.log('end4');
    console.log(data);
  });
}

test();
```

Comment: Thank you first choice what I need using babel can be compatible by all browsers